# Error ITMS-9000 .This bundle is invalid.

Tags: ios, xcode5, app-store-connect

After Bulid and Archive My project,When I Distribute it from the Organiser,Whlie Submitting it to the Itunes.IT Shows me two error Messages.
This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect..." and "This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID ..."

How can i resovle to this problem ,,, I am beginner to Xcode .
pls help!!!! ,,

Answer (score 0):

please check your itunesconnect bundle identifier and your app bundle identifier it should be same.because you are getting error due to your bundle identifier is mismatch with your itunesconnect bundle identifers. you can check also following link this is also suffering with your problem
The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value error